# What is "the nativist camp"?

Tags: definition

The second was the split between the free market, Liberal brexiteers, who envisaged Britain as open to the world, and **the nativist camp** led by Nigel Farage.

Could you please explain it to me as I can't find any information about it on the Internet.

Comment: Have you done any research at all? Nativism plus Neil Farage yields many results. Also, just nativist....which country are  you searching from?

Comment: I'm searching from the Russian Federation. I understand what nativism is, but there are little infromation about the camp and Nigel Farage. Perhaps, such sources of information are blocked here.

Comment: Ah, I thought so. I'll post some info.

Comment: You might ask this kind of question on [*Politics SE*](https://politics.stackexchange.com/), since the meaning of the phrase itself is not at issue.

Answer (score 2):

A meaning of *native* is "one who was born in a country" - it's the opposite of *immigrant* or *migrant*.

A meaning of *camp* is "side" - as in the sides in a conflict or contest.

Answer (score 1):

Nativism (politics)
From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
Nativism is the political policy of promoting the interests of native inhabitants against those of immigrants.[1] However, this is currently more commonly described as an anti-immigrant position.[2] In scholarly studies nativism is a standard technical term. The term is typically not accepted by those who hold this political view, however. Dindar (2010) wrote "nativists... do not consider themselves as nativists. For them it is a negative term and they rather consider themselves as 'Patriots'".[3]

Nativist is a term used in many places to criticize the idea of nativism, which is considered radical and dangerously close to extreme racism, etc. .

**Neil Farage is leader of the nativist camp in Britain. But he and those who espouse these views do not use the term to refer to themselves**.

Here is an example from Time Magazine:

Nigel Farage Claims Donald Trump's Election Win as 'Brexit Times Three'

By TARA JOHN November 9, 2016
The right-wing British politician who helped persuade Britain to vote to leave the European Union has claimed Donald Trump’s sweeping victory in the U.S. presidential election as the latest result of a populist wave that is set to upturn the political order in Europe in 2017. END QUOTE

Farage wanted Britain to leave the EU but his reasons for it were based on his nativist views, unlike the Liberals your article mentions.

In the US, horrible people like Steve Bannon have these same views. As I am American, I take the liberty of saying that about him. A real creep.

Camp in politics refers to people who all have the same views on something.